# mp3 bug after ffmpeg converting

Tags: mp3, ffmpeg

I'm converting wav (ima adpcm) to mp3 by ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i audio.wav -acodec libmp3lame audio.mp3
```

and play it in browser by html5.
But audio doesn't end at about 1-2 seconds from the end of file audio starts playing again. Same problem is in my audio player (aimp)

Where is the problem?

Problem with all wav file with "ima adpcm" audio format
CentOS
FFmpeg version SVN-r26402, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul  8 2011 15:37:30 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)
  configuration: --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis

Comment: *> But audio doesn't end at about 1-2 seconds from the end of file audio starts playing again* – that doesn't make sense, sorry. What exactly happens? What version of FFmpeg and LAME are you using? What is your operating system? Does this happen for all input files or just this one? Please [edit] your post to include more info.

Comment: Please also provide the complete ffmpeg console output that you get after entering your ffmpeg command.

Comment: consider also stating any other playback software you have tested the file with to ensure it is the mp3 and not the playback application.